# How to trigger javascript pop-up box by if-condition within the HTML code?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, popup

I created an html site where the user can input a code in a text input and then this code is being inserted in a MYSQL database if certain conditions are met. In case of a successfull database entry I would like to notify the user with a little pop up message, which displays something like "Success" and also stating some data from the table row, the code was inserted into. 
I found a nice looking pop up message on the following page, which I would like to use: https://www.gitto.tech/posts/animated-modal-box-using-html-css-and-javascript/.

However, in the implementation from the page, the pop-up is triggered by the click of a button:

```
  document.getElementById("open-popup-btn").addEventListener("click",function(){
  document.getElementsByClassName("popup")[0].classList.add("active");
});
 
document.getElementById("dismiss-popup-btn").addEventListener("click",function(){
document.getElementsByClassName("popup")[0].classList.remove("active");
});
```

I would like to execute the pop-up based on an if-condition, in which I check whether an php variable is already set:

```
<?php 
     if (isset($group)) {
?>    ......HTML code.....
```

So, can anybody tell me how to successfully remove that "onClick" function of the pop-up?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `<div class="popup<?php if (isset($group)) echo "active"; ?>">` although I'd submit the data via ajax then show the popup based on the server's reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you reload the page after said data was inserted into database?

If so, what you can do to show pop-up initially, is to simply add class `active` to your popup (element with class `popup`, like that:

```html
<div class="popup center active">
  ...
</div>
```

BUT

in order to be able to close the popup, you still will have to attach the second part of the provided script (you can simply insert it within `script` tags inside php `if` statement (at the end of HTML `body` element), like:

```html
<script>
  document.getElementById("dismiss-popup-btn").addEventListener("click",function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("popup")[0].classList.remove("active");
  });
</script>
```

note: It doesn't change the fact that, as said above - it would be better to handle this with [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) (e.g. via ajax)

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked! I have never worked with XHR, so I guess it will take a lot of time for to apply all the changes, right? Or is the implementation very similar to what I have so far?

Comment: Yes, you would have to setup e.g. API server to handle XHR requests, so it would require some work